# How to disable automatic sorting in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, sorting

I want to be able to arrange files in the file explorer in a certain order. Is there a way to disable the automatic sorting feature for folders?

It is possible to disable automatic sorting on the desktop (in fact it is disabled by default) so there must be a way to do so for folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there a way to disable the automatic sorting feature for folders?

Yes, it is possible.

> **How to Enable or Disable Auto Arrange in Folders in Windows 10**
>
> Information
>
> - When you drag and drop icons in a folder in Windows 10, they will automatically be aligned to a grid and auto arranged. By default,
>     disabling auto arrange and align to grid is not an available option in
>     File Explorer.
> - This tutorial will show you how to disable auto arrange and align to grid to be able to freely arrange icons how you like inside folders in
>     File Explorer for your account in Windows 10.
>
> Notes
>
> - When auto arrange is disabled, you can arrange items in any order and position in a folder using the extra large icons, large icons,
>     medium icons, or small icons view.
> - When auto arrange is disabled and you are using details view, you can only arrange items in any order in a folder, and not in any
>     position.
> - You will not be able to freely arrange items in a folder that are grouped. You can select Group by -> (None) in the View tab of the
>     ribbon to no longer have items in a folder grouped by a column.
> - You will not be able to freely arrange items in an opened library.
> - You can turn Auto arrange and Align to grid on or off as you like for individual folders while using the extra large icons, large icons,
>     medium icons, or small icons view. You would right click or press and
>     hold in the open folder, and click/tap on View to do so.

The source link includes detailed instructions and several batch files are available for download to:

- Disable Auto Arrange and use Details View by default
- Disable Auto Arrange and use Medium icons View by default
- Enable Auto Arrange and Reset Folder Views to Default

Source [Auto Arrange in Folders - Enable or Disable in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14856-auto-arrange-folders-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted, however can this site be trusted? I feel a bit queasy just downloading a batch file that does who knows what.

Comment: I can't guarantee anything, but I've never heard of any issues with tenforums.com or any of it's co-sites. For what it's worth the author or the article and of the batch files is Shawn Brink (https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4025086?fullName=shawn%20brink) a Microsoft MVP.

Comment: You should of course back up your registry first. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Comment: @Yin And you can inspect the batch files before running them.

Answer (score 0):

The hack of setting the FFlags has some side-effects that most sites don't tell. The following happens:

Tiles view option goes missing
When Preview pane is enabled in a folder, you’ll need to select a file first before you can double-click to open the file. (total 3 clicks). If you don’t use the Preview pane always, then no problem.
When you right-click an empty area in the folder when a file is selected, the right-click menu closes. You have to deselect the file first by clicking in a blank area.

The pros and cons of the method is is explained [here (Windows 10 - Disable Autoarrange)](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-full-row-select-auto-arrange-folders-windows-10/). Bonus: It also disables full row select.